# Can't upgrade npm from "npm install -g npm@latest" command

Tags: npm, npm-install

```sh
$ npm install -g npm@latest

/usr/local/bin/npm -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js\
/usr/local/bin/npx -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js\
npm ERR! code EACCES\
npm ERR! syscall mkdir\
npm ERR! path /usr/local/share/man/man1\
npm ERR! errno -13\
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/share/man/man1'\
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/share/man/man1']\
npm ERR!   cause:\
npm ERR!    { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/share/man/man1'\
npm ERR!      errno: -13,\
npm ERR!      code: 'EACCES',\
npm ERR!      syscall: 'mkdir',\
npm ERR!      path: '/usr/local/share/man/man1' },\
npm ERR!   stack:

npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir \'/usr/local/share/man/man1\'',\
npm ERR!   errno: -13,\
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',\
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',\
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/share/man/man1' }\
npm ERR! \
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.\
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user\
npm ERR!\ 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the\
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running\
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:\
npm ERR!     /home/katha/.npm/_logs/2021-05-13T12_20_16_050Z-debug.log
```

Comment: have to read ? [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm)

Comment: Can you provide more information about this issue?
Easy fix might be run `sudo npm install -g npm@latest` but I would not recommend that. Take a look at this articule https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally